# How can I directly insert a bitmap image instead of its existing path in MultipartEntity?

Tags: android

This is what I have so far:

```
MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
String strXMLFilename = "/sdcard/image.gif";
FileBody bin = new FileBody(new File(strXMLFilename));
File file = new File(bin);
reqEntity.addPart("file", bin);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Constants.getCameraData.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bao);
byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();                 
String photoName = photoNameEdit.getText().toString();
reqEntity.addPart("file", new ByteArrayBody(ba, photoName+".png"));
```